# Cloud Spanner streaming vs non-streaming queries performance difference

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

What is the performance difference between streaming and non-streaming queries, assuming the total result fits in the non-streaming max size?  Are there more round trips to Spanner on a streaming query even if the data fits in the maximum non-streaming size?

In my application, most queries that I run can be run as non-streaming queries but occasionally the result set size can be too big.  The simple solution is to switch all queries over to streaming queries, but I'm wondering what this will do to latency.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a performance advantage to using the non-streaming API. In fact, some of the official Cloud Spanner libraries only use the streaming variants.